# Webpage can't find html file to redirect to

Tags: php, google-app-engine

I have a google app engine PHP project. When I try to redirect to an html page, it fails with the error that it couldn't find the file specified.

In my PHP script, I have the following line of code:

```
 if (isset($_GET['modpack-news'])) {
   header('Location: news.html');
   exit;
```

When that line of code is run, It's supposed to redirect to that html page which is in the SAME directory as the script. (I tried it with the html file being in a different directory at first but that failed, so I put it in the same directory to see if it would cause the same issue and it did). When it redirects, I get this error:

[image: File not found]

I even tried manually setting the url to "https://wizardry-discord-bot.appspot.com/news.html"
but that returned the same error!

This is the project's tree:

[image: Project Tree]

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but I tried variations for the redirection path in the header line to stuff like "./news.html" to no avail.

What am I doing wrong and how do I make it so that I can access all of the files under `modpack` through the site's url directly?

This is my app.yaml if it's important:

```
runtime: php55
api_version: 1

handlers:
  - url: /*
    script: action.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `- url: /*` handler pattern matches `/news.html` as well, so instead of serving your `news.html` file it actually attempts to re-invoke `action.php`.

You need to add a handler for your HTML file(s) placed above the catch-all `/*` one.

I'd also suggest using the typical/more specific pattern for the PHP file based on the google [example](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/config/appref#example), to prevent the php script from being invoked for non-php file requests:

```
# Serve php scripts.
- url: /(.+\.php)$
  script: \1
```